# R with trivial topology is not locally Euclidean

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Question:
>
> Show that $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology is not locally Euclidean.

Attempt:

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set with the trivial topology $T_{t}=\left \{ \varnothing ,\mathbb{R} \right \}$
Let $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the set with the standard topology $T_{R}$.

> Recall:
> that a topological space X is locally Euclidean if $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \forall x \in X$ there is an open set $U \subseteq X $containing x that is homeomorphic to some open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
>
> By contrapositivity:
> that a topological space X is locally Euclidean if $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \forall x \in X$ there is an open set $U \subseteq X $containing x that is not homeomorphic to some open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

We assume a homeomorphism
$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$

f is homeomorphic to f is bijective, f and $f^{-1}$ is continuous between the topological spaces.

So we have
$f^{-1}: V\rightarrow U$

$f:U\rightarrow V$

So we have that

f maps open sets to open sets.
$f^{-1}\left ( \varnothing  \right )=\varnothing  \in T_{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

$f^{-1}\left ( \mathbb{R} \right ) \in T_{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

I would like some help is seeking a contradiction which would solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @egreg Every locally euclidean space is hausdorff??? You can have non-hausdorff manifolds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the former $\mathbb{R}$ being equipped with trivial topology. The preimage of any open neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ is non-empty and open, hence is $\mathbb{R}$. This simply implies $f(x)$ is a constant, thus cannot be a bijection.

Comment: The open sets in the topology on $R^{n}$ are open intervals for which there is a point x in that open interval.
The pre-image of that open interval maps that open intervals to a point in R, yes? But this violates the definition of a continuous map f that maps an open set to an open set. 
Did I understood this?

Comment: Your reasoning also works. But what I mean is: take a ball $B(f(x_0),\varepsilon)$ entered at $f(x_0)$ with radius $\varepsilon$. The continuity of $f$ implies $f^{-1}(B(f(x_0),\varepsilon))$ is non-empty(since it contains $x_0$) and open in the trivial topology of $\mathbb{R}$. So it has to be $\mathbb{R}$. This shows the image of $f$ is constrained in an arbitrarily small ball centered at $f(x_0)$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff, we have showed that all $f(x)$ equals $f(x_0)$. Now that $f$ is not even a injection, it can't be a homeomorphism.